# All had taken vs had all taken

Tags: word-usage

> The players **all had taken** a card
>   The players **had all taken** a card

Please can you explain the meaning of above sentences and 
why changing the position of "all"?

Comment: Not really, it is an adverb in either one. "*The players all* had taken a card" sounds literary though. Do these phrase have a source/context?

Comment: These sentences I have taken from rodney huddlestion's book Cambridge university, page 102, chapter 3verb

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to put **all** before **had** in this sentence.

In the second sentence, all is an adverb. it is normal to put an adverb next to the main verb- in this case before the verb:

> The players had **all taken** a card

When used as a pronoun, it is normally used before the auxiliary verb:

> **All** had taken a card

The second sentence sounds wrong because it seems that you have a pronoun following the noun that it represents:

> The **players all** had taken a card

There is actually one more valid option:

> All [of] the players had taken a card

Comment: These sentences,  I have taken from Rodney huddlestion's,  Cambridge university book,  page - 102 verb chapter 3